# SQL in foreach causes complication

Tags: php, sql

I have this code:

```
foreach($contactsResult AS $contactsRow) {
                echo $scrapProfileId = $contactsRow['profile_id'] . '<br />';
                echo $scrapUserId = $contactsRow['user_id'];

                $selectScrapQuery = 'SELECT scraps.user_id, scraps.scrap_text, scraps.profile_id, scraps.add_date, user.user_id, user.profile_picture_50
                                                FROM scraps
                                                JOIN user ON(scraps.user_id = user.user_id) 
                                                WHERE scraps.user_id =:scraps_user_id OR scraps.user_id =:own_user_id AND profile_id =:scraps_profile_id ORDER BY add_date';
                $prepSelectScrap = $conn->prepare($selectScrapQuery);
                $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scraps_user_id', $scrapUserId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                //$prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scraps_user_id', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':scraps_profile_id', $scrapProfileId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $prepSelectScrap->bindParam(':own_user_id', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $prepSelectScrap->execute();
                $scrapResult = $prepSelectScrap->fetchAll();
                $scrapResultCount = count($scrapResult);

                if($scrapResultCount > 0) {
                    foreach($scrapResult AS $scrapResultRow) {
                        echo    '<div class="parentArrow"></div>
                                        <div class="scrapItemParent">
                                            <img class="scrapProfilePic" src=" ' . $scrapResultRow['profile_picture_50'] . '" />
                                            <div class="scrapContent">' . $scrapResultRow['scrap_text'] . '<br />
                                            <span class="scrapTime">' . $scrapResultRow['add_date'] . '<br />' . $scrapResultRow['user_id'] . ' ' . $scrapResultRow['profile_id'] . '</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>';
                    }
                }
            }
```

In the WHERE clause there's the part that says:

```
scraps.user_id = :own_user_id
```

The problem is that this WHERE condition is being executed multiple times because the SQL is inside a foreach loop. I need the other WHERE conditions to be executed as long as it's needed, but the condition I mentioned above should only be executed once. This way, my own messages will not be displayed multiple times. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like you're trying to echo your rows before querying.

Comment: That's to see the issue. If I don't echo the rows it doesn't change anything.

Comment: $contactsRow can contains duplicate data?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The result from $contactsRow is 51 - 70, and 51 - 68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried left joining your USER table?

```
SELECT 
  scraps.user_id,
  scraps.scrap_text,
  scraps.profile_id,
  scraps.add_date,
  user.user_id,
  user.profile_picture_50 
FROM
  scraps 
  LEFT JOIN user 
    ON (scraps.user_id = user.user_id) 
WHERE scraps.user_id = :scraps_user_id 
  OR scraps.user_id = :own_user_id 
  AND profile_id = :scraps_profile_id 
ORDER BY add_date
```